# How to check SERP position correctly?

Tags: seo, google, search-results

I wonder how do you check your website's SERP position for a certain query.

I cannot directly go to Google and search, because it knows i'm looking for my site, and it shows it in the first position, but from another browser, it cannot be even in the first page. So how do you check for "average user" ?

I use Tor browser for that, since it gives me a completely different IP, do you think is it safe? I mean, does it give useful information ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the parameter `&pws=0` to the end of the search results' URL, it will turn personalisation off.

There's nothing such as "average user", it's same for all users (with some geolocalisation/targeting-based differences) except users that visit that website very often.

Tor does not store cookies and uses a different IP, so yes it's useful in this case to know what other people see, if that's what you mean by "safe".

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by safe. Wow, I didn't know we could turn personalisation off. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> Add the parameter &pws=0 to the end of the search results' URL, it will turn personalisation off.

It is good stuff.

Also I can suggest you the next:
You may use anonymous view. E.g. in Google Chrome simply press Ctrl+Shift+N. There is no cookies, cache and history here. In Firefox keys combination is Ctrl+Shift+P.
Then go to "Advanced Search" and set up language and region if you need.

Comment: yes private mode is good too, but I'm still concerned since my IP address is the same, and Google makes the personalization based on IP. Is is true ?

Comment: Yes, it is true. For fresh IP you may use VPN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of SERP trackers, special software for tracking your website SERP
Google Analytics can tell your position too yet, from my experience, it's not as good.